# Chat Server Client Output

Tags: java, class, client, server, chatroom

I am new to java. I am using NetBeans 8.0.2
I started a new project (Java -> Java Class Libary)
I have put two classes and run my code. There are no errors however, there is no output showing after building the project successfully.

I really appreciate your help.

My first class is ChatServer & my second one is ClientServer!

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatServer
{  private Socket          socket   = null;
   private ServerSocket    server   = null;
   private DataInputStream streamIn =  null;

   public ChatServer(int port)
   {  try
      {  System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
         server = new ServerSocket(port);  
         System.out.println("Server started: " + server);
         System.out.println("Waiting for a client ..."); 
         socket = server.accept();
         System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
         open();
         boolean done = false;
         while (!done)
         {  try
            {  String line = streamIn.readUTF();
               System.out.println(line);
               done = line.equals(".bye");
            }
            catch(IOException ioe)
            {  done = true;
            }
         }
         close();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println(ioe); 
      }
   }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {  streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
   {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
      if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  ChatServer server = null;
      if (args.length != 1)
         System.out.println("Usage: java ChatServer port");
      else
         server = new ChatServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
   }
}
```

---

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatClient
{  private Socket socket              = null;
   private DataInputStream  console   = null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;

   public ChatClient(String serverName, int serverPort)
   {  System.out.println("Establishing connection. Please wait ...");
      try
      {  socket = new Socket(serverName, serverPort);
         System.out.println("Connected: " + socket);
         start();
      }
      catch(UnknownHostException uhe)
      {  System.out.println("Host unknown: " + uhe.getMessage());
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ioe.getMessage());
      }
      String line = "";
      while (!line.equals(".bye"))
      {  try
         {  line = console.readLine();
            streamOut.writeUTF(line);
            streamOut.flush();
         }
         catch(IOException ioe)
         {  System.out.println("Sending error: " + ioe.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
   public void start() throws IOException
   {  console   = new DataInputStream(System.in);
      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   }
   public void stop()
   {  try
      {  if (console   != null)  console.close();
         if (streamOut != null)  streamOut.close();
         if (socket    != null)  socket.close();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println("Error closing ...");
      }
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  ChatClient client = null;
      if (args.length != 2)
         System.out.println("Usage: java ChatClient host port");
      else
         client = new ChatClient(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you running it with command line arguments?

Comment: Maybe you should not create a "Java Class Libary" but a "Java Application" instead. As the name says, its a library that can be used by other applications, not a application itself.

Comment: As I said I am new to java so what are command line!

Comment: I tried to create a Java Application but I really don't know what I am doing I put them inside classes inside an application still no output but it builds successful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run both ChatClient and ChatServer (hence the main methods in both classes).
Additionally, you need to pass command-line arguments. Let's take a look at `main()` in `ChatClient`:

```
public static void main(String args[])
   {  ChatClient client = null;
      if (args.length != 2)
         System.out.println("Usage: java ChatClient host port");
      else
         client = new ChatClient(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
   }
```

You're parsing the arguments to retrieve a server name and a port. This is an example of running those classes with proper parameters:

```
java ChatServer 55444
java ChatClient 127.0.0.1 55444
```

[Here](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html) is a short tutorial covering the issue of setting command-lind arguments in the Netbeans IDE.

Also, as @BDL pointed out, you'd better create a `New Project` instead of a java library (or even two projects for both a server and a client respectively).